# Регулярное выражение с перечислением директорий для конфигурации nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, синтаксис, location, syntax

Интересует, в чём может быть проблема с конструкцией следующего вида в конфигурационном файле nginx:

```
location ^~ /(bin|docs|extensions|includes|maintenance|mw-config|serialized|tests|skins|vendor)/ {
    internal;
}
```

На выходе не меняется ровным счётом ничего, в отличие от варианта, когда всё указано по отдельности:

```
location ^~ /bin/ { internal; }
location ^~ /docs/ { internal; }
location ^~ /extensions/ { internal; }
location ^~ /includes/ { internal; }
location ^~ /maintenance/ { internal; }
location ^~ /mw-config/ { internal; }
location ^~ /serialized/ { internal; }
location ^~ /tests/ { internal; }
location ^~ /skins/ { internal; }
location ^~ /vendor/ { internal; }
```

В этом случае получаю ошибку 404 (что и требуется).

То же самое происходит с конструкцией

```
location ^~ /resources/.+\.php$ {
    internal;
}
```

то есть, она не работает, в отличие от прямого указания на файл:

```
location ^~ /resources/Resources.php {
    internal;
}
```

Чтение https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location не приводит к просветлению относительно получаемых результатов.

Использую Nginx 1.14.2, официальный репозиторий, сборка для CentOS.

Comment: Потому что флаг `^~` не означает регулярное выражение. А вообще при таком количестве исключений кажется у вас просто плохая структура каталогов.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, плохо читал документацию.

Структура каталогов mediawiki, тут уж какая есть.